# How to load geo-localised informations based on map configuration and interaction

Tags: sql, database, asynchronous, gis, geospatial

I'm currently creating a new website based on geo-localised information to display on a map. I've never done this kind of development before, and my researches don't lead me to a decent result.

What I want to do is load a few POI on the map, say 15 by 15 until all POI are loaded on the map (This is to show the user that data is loading progressively).

I know how to load said POI 15 by 15 based on their update date in a scrollable list (Using limit and offset, but this implies that we have the same reference as a starting point), and now I want the same kind of behaviour, but based on their location instead of the timestamp.

What I'd like to do is trigger the update based on the center of the map when it moves, so that it starts loading POI in the displayed area, but without reloading what was already loaded.
I can't figure out how to do that.

Say the user moves the map to the side, but keeps some POI on the map, it should reload from the center to the edge of the map without re-adding the POI.
Also, when the user zooms out, it should load around the already present POI, as the center was already loaded on previous zoom.

The only think I was able to find and understand is how to sort POI based on a distance, with the Haversine formula from here:
http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/
But it doesn't cover the part where you interact with the map and need to load new data to add it to what's already there.

I'm using Leaflet to show information on the map and listen to events.
Any guidance welcome.